# How to use OpenCL 2.0 kernel language in Qt Creator?

Tags: qt, ide, opencl, qt-creator

Several days ago, when I started to learn OpenCL, I needed a good IDE to write OpenCL C kernel language, which provides some basic functions like syntax highlighting and static analysis. I was surprised to find out that Qt Creator is able to do the job.

Everything was fine until today I started to use some feature in OpenCL 2.0:

[image]

It looks like Qt Creator use libclang to do the parsing and libclang treats my source files as OpenCL 1.0. But My machine supports OpenCL 3.0 and the code was ok to compile and run. So I doubt it only supports OpenCL 1.0.

My questions are:

1. How to make Qt Creator (or the libclang plugin in it) support OpenCL 2.0?
2. How do you guys write OpenCL 2.0? Is there any better IDEs or editors?

Thank you guys, I am really a newbie here.

- I tried to rename the file's postfix to ".cl2", but it doesn't work.
- I read the [OpenCL support documentation of LLVM](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/OpenCLSupport.html), but failed to find out the solution.

Comment: Please don't post images with code
https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: @frank Sorry, dont know the rules. I was meant to show the error window, not the code. But thank you for your note. I will watch out next time.

Answer (score 1):

QtCreator uses KDE syntax highlighting engine. The definitions are simple XML files. You can find them [here](https://github.com/KDE/syntax-highlighting/tree/master/data/syntax), but opencl.xml doesn't look updated for 2.0/3.0 language. You can try to change it, and then put it into `$HOME/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/generic-highlighter/syntax` and it should pick it up.

In QtCreator, you can download newer definitions by going to Tools -> Options, select "Text editor" in left, then "Generic highlighter" tab. This will put the updated files in `$HOME.local/share/org.kde.syntax-highlighting/`

Comment: Thank you. I looked through the xml files, but found out that there is no definitions about showing a "function not found" error. So I think this is a "static analysis" problem, not a "syntax highlighting" problem. Any idea about how Qt Creator analyzes my code?